# What are these things on the top of Palpatine's throne and what is their function?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, death-star, object-identification

What are these things referred to in the Emperor Palpatine throne chair?

What is their function/job?

[image]

Comment: Those are either greeblies or blinkies

Comment: Shield generator, perhaps? https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_throne

Comment: [Call Attendant], [Call Vader], [Play Ominous Music]

Comment: [Request Diet Coke]

Comment: Recline, Extend Footrest

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep requesting illustrations. An answer might include them, but not having them doesn't preclude it being a good answer (e.g. if they're described in a novel, for example).

Comment: @Valorum Sorry, are there illustrations from
Star Wars blueprints or Star Wars archives & others

Comment: Massage upper back, massage lower back, massage heat level.

Answer (score 6):

The "Emperor Palpatine Chair Blueprints" identify the side controls on the arms.

[Star Wars: The Blueprints](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Blueprints)
[image]

Comment: An interesting find. Well done.